# MySQL- Trigger updating ranking

Tags: mysql, triggers, ranking

I'm creating a DB with "Team" table for some NFL teams, and I have assigned them all a ranking (standing in NFL), the attribute is called "Ranking".

I want to create a trigger such that if the ranking is updated, all of the others are updated appropriately.

However, I can't figure out a way to loop through the table. For example, assume team at rank 5 moves up to rank 3, how do I get the rank 3 to become 4, and then 4 to be 5?

If you need more info, feel free to ask, I'll provide it ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the id of the team to update (lets call it 42) and the old and new rank (old: 5, new: 3), then it's not too hard:

```
UPDATE Team SET rank=rank+1 WHERE rank BETWEEN 3 AND 5;
UPDATE Team SET rank=3 WHERE id=42;
```

Comment: Yeah, I will know the id that needs to be updated. I think this will work, let me check and I'll get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, my textbook never mentioned the BETWEEN command so I didn't know what to do, or even search for online.

Comment: You can replace `BETWEEN ... AND ...` with `rank >= 3 AND rank <= 5`