# Recalculating ranks after each item is voted on

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of items that users are allowed to vote on. In this table, there is a `votes` column, that holds the number of votes that item has accumulated, and a `rank` column, that is a ranking of all items based on the number of votes they have (i.e. most votes gets rank 1, second most gets rank 2, etc.)

Currently, I'm recalculating the rank of every item after every vote. That is, when a user votes, I add one to that item's `votes` column, and then update every rank with the following query:

```
SET @rank = 0
UPDATE items SET rank = @rank := @rank + 1 ORDER BY votes DESC
```

This works for the most part, but doesn't take in to account voting ties. If I have votes [10, 4, 3, 0], I would expect ranks `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. However, if I have votes `[10, 10, 3, 0]`, I would like ranks `[1, 1, 3, 4]`. This doesn't happen; I still get ranks `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

How can I incorporate ties like I've described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inelegant solution would return what you desire:

```
update ITEMS I1
   set rank =
         (select count(*)
            from ITEMS I2
           where I2.VOTES >= I1.VOTES)
         - (select count(*) - 1
              from ITEMS I3
             where I3.VOTES = I1.VOTES)
```

Comment: This works great, except it doesn't seem to update the rank data in the database; it only returns the new rank of each row.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't save the rank in database. You can calculate it while showing the result.

```
$rank = 1;
$lastVotes = -1;
$lastAdd = 0;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE * ORDER BY votes DESC", $link);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
  // local variable with votes
  $votes = $row['votes'];

  // check if we have a tie
  if( $lastVotes == $votes ) {
    // don't change rank if there is a tie but inc $lastAdd
    $lastAdd += 1;
  } else {
    // there is no tie: save last votes, adjust $rank and reset $lastAdd
    $lastVotes = $votes;
    $rank += $lastAdd;
    $lastAdd = 1;
  }

  // $rank is your rank
}
```

Comment: +1 for "I wouldn't save the rank in database".  When you save an aggregate or calculated value in another column the opportunity for them to get out of sync abound.  There are cases for it however and they are usually about performance.  In those cases a trigger and/or a separate table can be appropriate.  Analysis of usage is required for such performant issues.

Answer (score 0):

No mysql instance to try this out on, but how about something like this:

```
    SELECT v.id, v.votes, r.rank
      FROM votes v
          ,(SELECT votes, @rownum = @rownum + 1 AS rank
              FROM votes
              GROUP BY votes
              ORDER BY votes DESC
           ) r
      WHERE v.votes = r.votes
      ORDER BY rank
```

Figure out the distinct set of "votes", order them, give each a number, then use that to associate the number (rank) back to each vote.

Comment: Oh, and I should add that rank is a calculated value and I would  definitely not store this in the db either.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the table size, and on the freq of updates, but how about a trigger? [MySQL- Trigger updating ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851019/mysql-trigger-updating-ranking)